# Why React Testing Library is giving me an error when I use fireEvent on a input text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

So basically when I'm trying to make use of the "fireEvent" method from React Testing Library it just gives me an error telling me the following:

[image]

MainSection.test.js:

```
test('Check SearchBar functionality', async () => {
    render(<SearchBar />);

    const textInput = screen.getByTestId('text-input');

    fireEvent.change(textInput, { target: { value: 'mens cotton jacket' } });
});
```

SearchBar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css';

function SearchBar({ setSearch }) {
    return (
        <div className='search_bar'>
            <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Search here!'
                className='search_bar-text'
                data-testid='text-input'
                onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}></input>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SearchBar;
```

**Also, when I delete the "onChange" event from the input text, the test just pass (aka green).**

:/

Comment: `setSearch` is a prop. You're not providing that prop when you `render(...)` in your tests, so it's  undefined. I'd suggest using typescript or proptyping to prevent these kinds of errors.

Comment: Currently I don't work with TypeScript, could you give more details about that? Others code also don't have that prop that you are talking about and still working. Not even RTL's page has that.

Comment: Not really in-scope for a comment, or related to this question. But there are plenty of tutorials for setting up react + jest in typescript. It's not necessary to solve the problem, but either facebook's `prop-types` or typescript can be super helpful to make errors like this pop up earlier in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue to me appears to be that you're not providing the `setSearch` prop. I think an appropriate test for this component would look like this:

```
it("sets search text", () => {
    // mock out the work the parent component would
    // ordinarily do to provide a `setSearch` prop
    // by settting up a noop jest stub
    const setSearch = jest.fn();

    // note that we render w/ the setSearch prop
    // provided here, so it's not `undefined` later
    render(<SearchBar setSearch={setSearch} />);

    // fire the event we want to test behaviours for
    const textInput = screen.getByTestId('text-input');
    fireEvent.change(textInput, { target: { value: 'mens cotton jacket' } });

    // assert that `setSearch` was called how we expected
    // as this is part of the component's public interface
    expect(setSearch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(setSearch).toHaveBeenCalledWith("mens cotton jacket");
});
```